# jquery error in for loop with append

Tags: jquery, variables, for-loop

I have a for loop nested in a for loop, where I'm trying to append some dynamically created elements, and I keep getting the error: 'Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function', and I'm not sure why.  Here's what I have:

HTML:

```
<div class="particle"></div>
```

JS:

```
number_of_particles = 30 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 40);
number_of_layers =  3 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
$particle = $(".particle");

for ( var i = 0; i < number_of_layers; i++ ) {
    var paralax_speed, $particle_layer, $particle_layer_particle;

    paralax_speed = Math.random().toFixed(2);
    $particle_layer = "<div class='particle-layer' data-stellar-ratio='" + paralax_speed + "'></div>";
    for ( var i = 0; i < number_of_particles; i++ ) {
        $particle_layer_particle = "<div class='particle'></div>";
        $particle_layer.append($particle_layer_particle);
    }
    $particle.append($particle_layer);
}
```

Comment: $particle_layer = $("<div class='particle-layer' data-stellar-ratio='" + paralax_speed + "'></div>"); should do it

Comment: Note how both loops use `i` <- bad idea !

Comment: micheal that worked, thank you, if you add it as an answer I'll accept.  Just makes a Jquery object right?

Comment: adeneo what's another good variable name instead of i?

Comment: Uhm, `j` .. no wait . .. `k` , or maybe `l` ... ouch, can't decide !

Comment: @adeneo use z like in `zzzzzzzzzzzz`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a jQuery object:

```
$particle_layer = $("<div class='particle-layer' data-stellar-ratio='" + paralax_speed + "'></div>");
```

And two for-loops:

```
var i, j;
for (i = ...)
    for (j = ...)
```

Comment: one more question, these are getting a style of display:none put on them for some reason, any idea why that's happening?

Comment: @loriensleafs Ask new question, this is completly unrelevant to opened question. And don't forget to mark this answer as accepted one (and you can still upvote it btw)

Comment: Check your CSS, one quick way is through the F12 tools. @A. Wolff, I agree!